# using css on echo php table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Below is my code which calls for a table to be created using php, it has very basic styling on it.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM League ORDER BY Points DESC, Difference DESC, TeamName DESC");
    echo "<style>#size{height:100px;width:340px;overflow-y:scroll;}</style>";
    echo "<table id='size' border='1'>;
            <tr>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Played</th>
            <th>Won</th>
            <th>Drawn</th>
            <th>Lost</th>
            <th>For</th>
            <th>Against</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
            <th>Bonus Pts</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['TeamName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Played'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['W'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['L'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['D'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['PF'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['PA'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Difference'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['BonusPoints'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I have also created a way to style it in my CSS file below is the code

```
#customers
{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#customers td, #customers th 
{
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #98bf21;
    padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#customers th 
{
    font-size:1.1em;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#A7C942;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

I'm aware that my table is not using the customer id for the table, but when I did it wouldn't work. So I added the simple styling at the top to see if it works and it did. Any suggestions how i can get it to use the customers styling? thanks

Comment: Did you include css file to you html? If so, there is no reason that `#customers` as table id should not work (try ctrl+f5 to refresh browser cache)

Comment: your css defines styles for the css id `customers` and your table has id `size` so obviously that won't work right?

Comment: i used to style to make a simple styling to see if it works it did. When i put customers in it didnt

Comment: change `echo "<table id='size' border='1'>;` to `echo "<table id='customers' border='1'>;`

Comment: @mark i have this in my header file <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="./css/websitestyle.css" />
 </head>

Comment: Is your header in your php file?

Comment: its working now must of been some kind of syntax error :/ when i get enough reputation ill upvote you all for the support

Answer (score 1):

As you are declaring your style can only be declared in head section of page..

Use style in this manner when u are declaring inside the code..

```
<?php

echo "<table id='size' style='height:100px;width:340px;overflow-y:scroll;' border='1'>";
```